# Linq query & vs &&

Tags: c#, linq, logical-operators

I saw a code  with & in linq condition

```
 var highestApplicationStatus = (from status in ctx.ApplicationStatuses.Where(o => o.ApplicationId == Application.ApplicationId & o.IsDeleted == false & o.StatusDate != null).OrderByDescending(o => o.ApplicationStatusType.DisplayOrder) select status).FirstOrDefault();
```

I rewrote it using &&

```
  var highestApplicationStatus = (from status in ctx.ApplicationStatuses.Where(o => o.ApplicationId == Application.ApplicationId && o.IsDeleted == false && o.StatusDate != null).OrderByDescending(o => o.ApplicationStatusType.DisplayOrder) select status).FirstOrDefault();
```

There has been a bug  while released and   i have been asked about this change. My understanding was that  && is used for Logical And    where as & is for bit wise  operation .  One team member was suggesting that  &  / && are same in Linq Environment.  Can someone explain  the difference

Comment: Use `&&`. Whomever is defending use of `&` in this context is wrong.

Comment: Yes, some providers *may* treat them as equivalent (e.g. when generating SQL). Nonetheless, you should use `&&`.

Comment: An aside comment: never ever change any existing code that looks wrong.

Comment: @JimG., I read through it, but the question  is  specific to linq query

Comment: @Antediluvian Well, _verify_ that it’s wrong first, *then* tidy it up. And test it in a staging environment first!

Comment: You're asking 2 questions:

1. Should `&&` or `&` be used?
2. Should I have changed the code if I think there is a bug in it?

The may have different answers. In your case the answers may be true and false respectively.

Comment: @Antediluvian The counter argument is that this code is likely to be copied and reused elsewhere. Spurring further (pointless) discussion about the differences between `&` and `&&` etc. With 99.9% certainty, `&&` was meant (i.e. should have been used) here. _Obviously you still need to test it, to be 100% sure._

Comment: In this context, `&&` just causes the logic to short-circuit on the first false evaluation. With `&`, it actually evaluates all expressions. In order for your fix to have broken something, there would need to be some critical logic occurring in the `IsDeleted` and/or `StatusDate` properties that would have been prevented by the short circuit operator.

Comment: `With '&', it actually evaluates all expressions` @oscilatingcretin That is true for LINQ to Objects. It is not _necessarily_ true for all LINQ query providers. In practical terms, `&` is only useful in this general context if you have code in your projection with side effects (and if that is the case, well you have bigger issues).